# kendoUI Grid Header Custom Menu

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to show a kendomenu at the click on the column header of kendo grid.
Someone have some idea how can i do?

I try with columnmenu but is not customizable.. i want to create a custom menu for each column.

Comment: After you create the grid, I guess you can replace/merge the column headers with your kendoMenu. Do you have a sample with jsFiddle so we can try?

Comment: at the end i have created a menu and bind the event 'click on the header column grid' and show my custom menu.

Thanks